# Concatenate if valid length - c#

Tags: c#, string, concatenation

I know what to do for this question, the issue I am having is executing the idea with the correct code - this is a part of the learning process, I guess.

I need help with this question that I have tried:

*Return the full name separated by a single space character, if the length of the new string equals or exceeds 10. Otherwise return "Not valid input".*

```
public static string ConcatIfValidLength(string firstName, string 
secondName) 
{ 
throw new NotImplementedException(); 
}
```

The way I would go about doing this is:
---> join the two strings 'firstName' and 'secondName' 
---> use a function which calculates the length of this new string (minus the single space character - this should go in the next step)
---> use an if function on the previous step, with the condition that it must be <= 10 characters
---> Otherwise 'return "Not valid input"'

In terms of code, I have experimented with the Join Strings and .Length functions, as a well as the if function, but can't get the right code yet.

```
 public static string ConcatIfValidLength(string firstName, string 
 secondName)
    {

        return firstName.Length + secondName.Length >= 10
            ? firstName + " " + secondName
            : "Not valid input";

    }
```

If my question sounds stupid, please bear in mind I am a rookie learning on the go and I haven't seen any duplicates.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the code you have and the exact 'question'. What went wrong with Length and Join?

Comment: "if the length of the new string equals or exceeds 10" - this sounds wrong (it means 10 or *more* characters). Did you mean that the length of the combined string should be 10 or *less*?

Comment: Yes, you're right, that's an error on my part. I meant >= 10

Comment: Okay, so first name `"John"`, last name `"Doe"` would be *invalid* (because the combined length is < 10), while first name `"Benedict"`, last name `"Cumberbatch"` would be *valid* (because the combined length is >= 10) and the expected result would be `"Benedict Cumberbatch"`, right?

Comment: @ Corak - that's correct

Comment: @ Corak and @ Vlad - please cvheck the edit of my post above. Am I missing anything in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string ConcatIfValidLength( string firstName, string secondName )
    {
        if ( firstName == null )
            throw new ArgumentNullException( "firstName" );
        if ( secondName == null )
            throw new ArgumentNullException( "secondName" );

        return firstName.Length + secondName.Length + 1 >= 10
            ? firstName + ' ' + secondName
            : "Not valid input";
    }
```

Comment: Show your input strings and expected result

Comment: Still doesn't work, unfortunately. I've plugged in exactly what you have done

Comment: @S.Dan Not compile or not correct result? I change example now, try this.

Comment: Test case failed. Invoked method with (Andy, Smith). Expected (Andy Smith), received ( Not valid input ).

Comment: @S.Dan The size of total string must be 10 or greathrer with white space character, right? Fix it, try now.

Answer (score -1):

// I added 1 to condition, because total max length with single blank space equal to 11.. but if it's not must for you, ignore it.. engoy!

```
   public static string ConcatIfValidLength(string fName, string lName)
    {
    if (fName.Length + lName.Length + 1 > 10)
      return "Not Valid!";
    else
      return fName + " " + lName;  
    }
```

Comment: this is not correct, he wants to return Name and lastName if length is LONGER than 10, not the other way, so all you have to do is switch the returns